# throwing and catching exception from function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

```
function connectTo(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
            throw "Troubles.";
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

try {
    connectTo("http://www.google.com");
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Exception happend.');
}
```

Perhaps the "catch" part will execute (in console appears the message), but the exception stays uncatched (= in console appears "Uncaught Troubles.").
Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the throw does not bubble up through a callback like that. Pass in an error handling callback and deal with it manually.

Let me illustrate your stack traces

There is no stacktrace connection between the onreadystatechange function and the connectTo function. So when you throw an error it never bubbles up to the try catch block around connectTo.

What firefox is doing is saying `"Oh you did something that doesn't work. let me fix that for you and do what you think it does"`

```
function connectTo(url, err) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
            err.call(this, new Error("troubles"));
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

connectTo("http://www.google.com", function(e) {
     console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: OK then, but why is here try {} catch() available for use?

Comment: I'm not talking about your code here, i'm just saying, why i cannot use try {} catch() {} generaly for catching exceptions?

Comment: @RadekSimko you can but the onreadystate function is not in the connectTo function chain. It doesnt bubble up

Comment: so it means the try-catch catches only exceptions in 1-level function? if there is a function, which calls another function and the second throws exception, it has to be catched in the function which calls it?

Comment: @RadekSimko you never call the onreadystatechange function. Its asynchronously handled by the browser.

Comment: Explicit Error Handling 1 - Exceptions 0: Will take this example for the next discussion about error handling in golang ;-)